# jira update ticket using script

Tags: hudson, jenkins, jira

Is there any way update Jira ticket using scripts?

Basically I will have a build from hudson/jenkins and if I get the Jira ID in all changes then corresponding ID should be updated to release version in Jira? Can any one help me? I am bit new to Jira admin.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult to understand the question but there is a Jira plugin for jenkins that does what I think you're asking:

Here is a link to the [Jenkins JIRA plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin), you'll need to make sure the web service API for JIRA is enabled in the JIRA admin interface.

Comment: You know very nicely integrated but the issue is it pollutes the comment section by adding recent changes of Jekins in Jira cooment section any idea to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

JIRA has a SOAP (and in some version REST) web service that would allow you to make an HTTP request to JIRA to make changes to a ticket. If the Jenkins plugin that Mike K suggested does not work for you, then you can look at writing a script that would make the request that you need.

Comment: Well, but it will update only comment section taht I already integrated, is there any way to  update the section Fix Version/s: XXXX in the jira ticket page.

Comment: You mean the Jenkins plugin will only update the comment? Cause the SOAP API will allow you to edit just about anything in the ticket. So you may want to look at going that route.

Comment: Yes, but wanted update that Fix/Versions in that particular ticket, and that Jenkins jira plugin works great.